# Undo LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

I want to add an **Undo** method to the `LinkedList` class that reverses the last operation done on the list. What is the best way to go about undoing these commands?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Your thought seems to be pretty nice , and i would suggest to go with storing your actions in stack , like store the last function call in stack and if you want to redo the things just pop out check , compare , write a function which redoes it and VOILA !